# Using Interface for DbContext causes issue with subquery

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am using an interface for DbContext so that I can write unit tests for my Service Layer with out depending on concrete DbContext. This doesn't seem to work well when there are sub-queries in LINQ statements.

Here is a simple test that I put to test EF5 .

I declared an interface for my Db Context

```
public interface IDbContext
    {
        #region DbContext public properties
        DbChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; }
        DbContextConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        Database Database { get; }
        #endregion

        #region DbContext public methods
        IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors();
        DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity);
        DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
        DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
        DbSet Set(Type entityType);
        int SaveChanges();
        #endregion
    }

    public interface ISchoolContext : IDbContext,IDisposable
    {
        DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

And then my SchoolEntities implements the above interface

```
public partial class SchoolEntities : DbContext, ISchoolContext
```

The below code throws an error "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'TestEF.Course'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context".

```
*ISchoolContext* ctx = new SchoolEntities()
var query = from dep in ctx.Departments where dep.Budget > 0 && !ctx.Courses.Any(c => c.DepartmentID == dep.DepartmentID) select dep.DepartmentID;
```

The above code works fine if I replace ISchoolContext declaration with SchoolEntities.

```
SchoolEntities ctx = new SchoolEntities()
```

Note: Also the code works fine with interface in EF6. Does this mean that this is a bug in EF5? If it is a bug is there any hack for this?

Thanks for reading a long post.

Comment: I do seem to remember past versions of Entity Framework not working as nicely with interfaces. This is likely something that just wasn't really supported in older versions, and support was added recently.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering a very weird behavior. Could you try this query with your example ? It should be equal to yours but using a left join.

```
var query = from dep in ctx.Departments
            join course in ctx.Courses
                on dep.DepartmentID equals course.DepartmentID into leftJoin
            from courseLeftJoin in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where dep.Budget > 0 && courseLeftJoin == null
            select dep.DepartmentID;
```

Let me know if it works with the interface.

**EDIT:**

Good to hear this query works. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with EF5. Could you reinstall EF5 5.0.0 ?

For that, please open a **Package Manager Console** (available in the menu Tools > NuGet Packet Manager) to run this command:

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0

This above line can be found on the [official website](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0) of NuGet.

**EDIT2:**

After testing your code, I was able to reproduce the issue. I saw the exception was thrown at `System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)`. Using a decompiler, I was able to find the line that throws the `NotSupportedException`.

Then, I compared this function with EF5 and EF6. Here is the result: [image].

I'm unable to say why this error occurs, but I suspect the implementation of EF5 doesn't handle your case, unfortunately.

I tried your code with the code-first approach and it succeeded. This issue must be related to the designer approach (EDMX).

Comment: Yes, this works. I am still not able to understand how an interface declaration can cause such a weird behavior.

Comment: Good. Please try to reinstall the package as described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I did try re-installing EF5 and didn't work. As I mentioned If i update to EF6 it works. I have put a test solution @ https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=401B8F228E425257!112&authkey=!ALVYu8rdZdRll2A&ithint=file%2c.zip